# Attaching source for some classes in a jar

Tags: java, jar, reverse-engineering, decompiling, decompiler

For our project we are doing kind of reverse engineering.
For that we have to debug a third party jar.

I tried de-compiling that jar with DJ, JAD, but output is source code with compile time errors (say return type is boolean in method prototype, but returning int, broken for loops, etc...).

Now, out of this corrupted source code, there are few .java files, which I want to debug.
And I want to attach these few files source code with the corresponding classes in jar.

I googled for this, but not found anything useful.
????

Comment: If you are running from a jar the attached source code doesn't have to compile.  Is the jar compiled with debugging information, if it is your lines numbers have to match, otherwise you can't debug the classes.

Comment: Manifest.MF says :-  Manifest-Version: 1.0        
                     Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.5.4 
                     Created-By: 1.4.2_05-b04 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blocker is that the decompilers most likely are unable to rewrite a source file with correct line numbers. So even if the compiled lib has the appropriate line number information, using the decompiled output out of the box won't work.

You will be able to set breakpoints in method (as long as line number information is available in the compiled class files) even without haveing the source code. You may even be able to read the values of local variables (again, if the classes have been compiled with debug information) but then you have to look at the decompiler output and hope for the best, that the decompiled method is close enough to the real code.

It is not impossible but requires some "manual" work.

Comment: Thanks. After giving some manual efforts, i have the setup working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention which IDE you are using for debugging. Eclipse asks for the sources if trying to debug classes which are only available in class form. The main problem is as Andreas_D already mentioned the non-matching line numbers.

I would try the following.

1. Delete all decompiled java files with has not
   been decompiled in a working state.
2. Try to compile each working
   decompiled java file using the
   original JAR in classpath. This
   allows you to generate new class
   files with correct line infos for
   debugging.
3. Now replace the class files in the
   JAR file with the ones you have
   successfully recompiled. Add also
   the java files. Your debugging IDE
   should automatically recognize the
   source files then.

Answer (score 0):

To attach source code for a class in java code :

- Right-click on the desired class
- Go to Open Declaration **[F3]** 

  *Class File editor will open click on Attach Source button*
- Browse jar which has source code
- Click <Ok>
  *After doing above step,Open Declaration will open .class file having source code.*